# Magnetic Fields in water

Tags: magnetic-fields, water

I have a question for all of the persons talking about magnetism.  What are the differences in any of the properties, laws, etc. of a magnetic field totally submerged in water compared to a magnetic field not submerged in water?

Comment: [Magnetic susceptibility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_susceptibility) and [Magnetic permeability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permeability_(electromagnetism)) will likely change in the water, but I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for. Could you clarify your issue a little bit?

Comment: How do the push and pull magnetic forces (magnetic susceptibility) change when totally submerged in water? Is there a modification to an existing formula accounting for water submersion for magnetic susceptibility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Water is actually not a non-magnetic material that many people seem to think it is, it is actually [diamagnetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamagnetism). This means that it will *reduce* the external magnetic field by aligning anti-parallel to the field.

However, water has a [susceptibility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_susceptibility) on the order of $\chi_v\simeq-10^{-5}$. This will change the strength of the magnetic attraction by about 0.001%, which really isn't a significant change. I suppose, though, if you had sensitive enough equipment, it *could* be detected, but for most practical purposes it is a negligible effect.

As the effect is known, the modification is already in place:
$$\mathbf{B}=\mu_0\left(1+\chi_v\right)\mathbf{H}$$
Since water has a negative value for the susceptibility, then
$$\mathbf{B}\lesssim\mu_0\mathbf{H}$$

Comment: This answer is very interesting, as I have yet another question that really changes things now on my other question.

Comment: Look for my other question I posted after this one please:  Can a magnetic field hold a state of supercavitation if a magnetic field could be placed inside of the bubble of the supercavitation?